# Solving a projectile trajectory problem

Tags: physics, homework

Hoping someone is able to help me with this problem. I will post the problem and what I am having issues with to allow you to better understand the problem.

[image: Problem]

So I graphed this using the parametric plot command and it outputted this graph.

[image: Graph]

Assuming I actually graphed this right, I recognize the value for when the bullet hits the ground is when "y=0" or the "x-intercept." You can see on the graph an "x-intercept" appears around 15000, how can I find the exact value of where it crosses the x-axis?

I tried

```
FindRoot[{x[t], y[t]}, {x, 15000}]
```

but this only gave me errors saying the function value is not a list of numbers with dimensions.

How can I get the exact value from my parametric graph where the bullet hits the ground?

Comment: `x[t]/.FindRoot[y[t],{t,70}]`. FindRoot finds the value of t for which `y[t]` is zero in the form of a rule, `{t->57.723}`. Then `x[t]/.{t->57.723}` returns `x[57.723]`.

Comment: I used your code x[t]/.FindRoot[y[t],{t,70}] and got 16326.5 back as an output. Does this sound right? Also do you think I graphed it right aswell? I am confused by the rest of your advice as to how you got 57.723

Comment: Your parametric plot is correct. `FindRoot` is solving the equation `y[t]=0` for `t`, using the best guess of `t=70` as a starting point. Once you've found the time at which the projectile hits the ground (`y=0`) you can ask what it's `x` position was at that time as well. `x[t]/.FindRoot[...]` is just an idiomatic way to use the output of `FindRoot` to compute the value `x[57.723]`. From your plot the value of 16236.5 looks pretty close to the x-intercept, which you guessed was about 15000.

Comment: Okay, so I take the value and use x[t]/.FindRoot[x[t],{x,16236.5}] to get the value of t when it hits the ground? @N.J.Evans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already proposed in the comments

```
d = Pi/4;
v0 = 400;
g = 9.8;

x[t_] := t v0 Cos[d]
y[t_] := t v0 Sin[d] - 1/2 g t^2

x0 = x[t] /. FindRoot[y[t], {t, 50}]
```

> 16326.5

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 70},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x0, 0}]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

Time is

```
First @ Solve[y[t] == 0 && t > 0, t, Reals]
```

[image]

(You can also use `Solve`)

Comment: Yes but this solution only gives the distance traveled by the bullet if I am correct, 16325. The question I am on is requesting the time, so how can I find the time from this information?

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is purely graphical approach to find the values of `x` and `t` where `y[t] ==0`. With sufficiently large value for `PlotPoints` this approach gives the same results as the ones obtained using several steps of `Solve`.

```
Legended[plt = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 70}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {If[# > 0, #2]&}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]], PlotPoints -> 200],  
 SwatchLegend[{Red}, 
      {Panel@Grid[{{"x = " , x0 = Cases[Normal @ plt, Point[x_] :> x[[1]], ∞][[1]]},
      {"t = " , InverseFunction[x][x0]}}]}, 
      LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"]]
```

[image]